# Including XML code snippet in JSP

Tags: xml, jsp

How can I include a piece of XML code in JSP without parsing it? I am using plain JSP and not using JSTL or EL. This is what I have done but it parses the XML code snippet and display the pageViewEventXml on top of the page, which I dont want to happen.

```
home.jsp
==============
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>istore - Home Page</title>
    <jsp:include page="event.jsp"/>
</head>
<body>My Home Page</body>
</html>

event.jsp
============
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.istore.utils.GenericUtils"%>
<%
    String pageViewEventXml = GenericUtils.getAttribute(request, "pageViewEventXml");
%>
<![CDATA[<%= pageViewEventXml%>]]>
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

No worries I got the answer. Missed the "script" tags

```
<%@page import="com.istore.utils.GenericUtils"%>
<%
    String pageViewEventXml = GenericUtils.getAttribute(request, "pageViewEventXml");
%>
<script>
    <![CDATA[
      <%= pageViewEventXml%>
    ]] >
</script>
```